# .Net 6 issue with DataGrid Virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-6.0

I’m trying implement virtualization using DataGrid according with article from Paul McClean “WPF: Data Virtualization” ([WPF: Data Virtualization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)).
I made ItemsProvider and VirtualizingCollection(implemented IList, INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces). On NETFramework 4.8 all works fine, but in .Net 6 project DataGrid request all rows ignoring virtualization.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="False"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
          ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
```

I search possible solution here, but all that suggested options doesn't help.
What I missing?

Comment: The article says "when an ItemsControl is bound to an IList implementation, rather than an IEnumerable implementation, it will not enumerate the entire list." However in my experience, like you, I find the ItemsControl pulls every member of the collection immediately. I can't say if this is a Framework vs. Core issue or not. Because of this I employ a different solution than the codeproject article, one involving an intermediary object and a lazy load. Happy to post details if it would be of value.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion Seems, that in .Net was changed DataGrid behavior in this case.
If you can show your implementation - will be great. At this moment I'm looking more practicaly way to work with large amount of data. Any ideas may help)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier. Busy day. I'll try to find time to post a proper answer tomorrow. The gist is that you create an intermediary view model to encapsulate data that may or may not actually be loaded. You then bind to a member of that class - say Data - whose getter returns an initial placeholder but then activates or adds to an asynchronous load queue. When the real data loads you trigger a property change notice. I believe I got the idea from a different CP article so if I can find that it might even be more helpful to you and any other potential readers.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion not sure, that I correctly understand your idea, you have service, which load first page and by some trigger load next page. From view model you fill UI collection, using notification event from service when data was loaded and required show it to user?

Link to article or code will helpful for me for better understanding implementation

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion Many thanks for your answers. Seems, that I've solve my issue. Problem was solved by renaming property in data object from `Fields` to `FieldValues` (I use collection for more flexible data displaying on UI). How it affected the grid - I do not understand, may be DataGrid try handle Fields property by self algorithm.